# Accessing a master page from httphandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I am developing a small application in asp.net (writing in c#).
In my application I am using jquery to perform asynchronous call to the server.
I have an http handler that listens in to the requests and does what it needs to do.

Problems start when in the handler I need to access information stored in the page , from where the asynchronous call started. When I try this:

```
 Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
```

I don't get a page.

How else can I access the page itself?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't send the needed data as parameters to the async call? It seems that you have access to the information on the calling page.

Comment: well, my master page holds some very complex datatypes. I am forced to have these datatypes exposed through the master page from another design I am working with. 

I can save the datatypes to the session, but every once in a while I need to refresh the objects I am working on by requesting them from my master page again.

The information is per user, so I cannot solve it by exposing a static method from the master page.

Comment: I think you have to add some more detail in order for us to understand you specific need, but in general i agree with @Bryan in that you have a design issue. You shouldn't try to access the master page from a HttpHandler.

Comment: Really, it sounds like you don't need a custom HttpHandler, you just need some WebMethod(s) on your Page.  I find that, in general, HttpHandlers are best used for tasks that are simple, specific, and self-encapsulating.

Answer (score 3):

You have a slight design issue.  The Page class IS an HttpHandler.  It is in fact the *default* HttpHandler that handles requests.  When you define your own HttpHandler, there is no Page class... and hence no Master either.

If you need to access information from a different page, you need to do that via the normal ASP.NET mechanisms... Session, Cache, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can create new instance of page.

```
SomePage page = new SomePage();
```

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree here.  This might get you a Page class, but it will have nothing to do with the Request being handled.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you Bryan. But it answers the question.